# How to capture the label of a checked radio button in jquery

Tags: jquery, text, radio-button, checked

I have this block of markup:

```
<fieldset class="form__list form__inlineButtons" enabled="enabled">
<label for="paymentMethod_839838" class="form__optional">
<input type="radio" value="1" name="paymentMethod" id="paymentMethod_839838" class="form__list jq__pmt1" style="display: inline-block;"> Cash
</label>
<label for="paymentMethod_570709" class="form__optional">
<input type="radio" value="2" name="paymentMethod" id="paymentMethod_570709" class="form__list jq__pmt2" style="display: inline-block;"> Check
</label>
<label for="paymentMethod_692392" class="form__optional">
<input type="radio" value="3" name="paymentMethod" id="paymentMethod_692392" class="form__list jq__pmt3" style="display: inline-block;"> Credit Card
</label>
<label for="paymentMethod_567739" class="form__optional">
<input type="radio" value="4" name="paymentMethod" id="paymentMethod_567739" class="form__list jq__pmt4" style="display: inline-block;"> Invoice
</label>
<label for="paymentMethod_227750" class="form__optional">
<input type="radio" value="5" name="paymentMethod" id="paymentMethod_227750" class="form__list jq__pmt5" style="display: inline-block;"> Payment Pending
</label>
</fieldset>
```

I have this jquery:

```
$('[name="paymentMethod"]').change(function() {
alert( $('[name="paymentMethod"] :radio:checked + label').text() );
}); // end .change()
```

I can't seem to capture the label of the checked radio button

Comment: A sidenote: label `for` attribute is optional when input is child of label

Comment: Ok, thanks @Satpal. The markup is generated from an open source tool I am using so I have no control over its creation. I am merely trying to work with it to add my own layer of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it like this -

```
$('[name="paymentMethod"]').change(function() {
    var label = $(this).closest('label').text();
    alert(label);
}); // end .change()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MBz4k/